# Need Help Operator Overloading So I Can Display Functions

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to overload the << operator so I can display my rational class functions.

These are the lines I'm trying to overload:

```
cout << "Testing the compare() member function, found:" << endl;
if (r1.compare(r2) == 1)
  cout << r1.display() << " is greater than " << r2.display() << endl;
else if (r1.compare(r2) == 0)
  cout << r1.display() << " is equal to " << r2.display() << endl;
else if (r1.compare(r2) == -1)
  cout << r1.display() << " is less than " << r2.display() << endl;

cout << "Testing the four arithmetic member functions:" << endl;
cout << "r1 + r2 = " << r1.display() << " + " << r2.display() << " = " << r1.add(r2) << endl;
cout << "r1 - r2 = " << r1.display() << " - " << r2.display() << " = " << r1.subtract(r2) << endl;
cout << "r1 * r2 = " << r1.display() << " * " << r2.display() << " = " << r1.multiply(r2) << endl;
cout << "r1 / r2 = " << r1.display() << " / " << r2.display() << " = " << r1.divide(r2) << endl;
```

The errors occur everytime I call a function. Here is the code for the functions:

```
void rational::display()
{
   int gcd = GCD();
   if (denom < 0)
   {
      num = -num;
      cout << num / gcd << " / " << denom / gcd << endl;
   }
   else if (num == 0)
   cout << num << endl;
}

rational rational::add(const rational &r2) const
{
   rational sum; 
   sum.num = (num * r2.denom) + (r2.num * denom);
   sum.denom = denom * r2.denom;
   return sum;
}
```

The multiply, divide, and subtract functions are as same as the add they just have the symbols and variable name changed to match the operation. My overload operator is set up like this:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, rational &robj)
{
   out << example code << example code;
   return out;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is my first time posting so if I need to post more of my code I will. Thanks!

Comment: What errors occur?  Be as specific as possible.

Comment: So for this line: cout << r1.display() << " is greater than " << r2.display() << endl; I get an error like this: [Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'void')

Comment: Not sure of your error, but try `const rational &robj` in your stream operator.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, rational &robj)
```

to

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, rational const& robj)
```

Then, instead of

```
cout << r1.display() << " is greater than " << r2.display() << endl;
```

use

```
cout << r1 << " is greater than " << r2 << endl;
```

Since you already have the above `operator<<` function, I would get rid of the member function `display()`. It doesn't (should not) give you any more functionality than using the `operator<<` function.

Given

```
rational 1
```

Use of

```
r.display();
```

should give you the same output as

```
cout << r << endl;
```

---

See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for more details on operator overloading.

Comment: I got it to work but I have a function that has a variable passed through like this: r1.add(r2). How would I define this in the >> overload? Putting r1 (r2) in the main gives me an error.

Comment: @LunyJake, Glad to hear you got thinks working. I think it will be better to create another post for such a question.